# Group days to weeks in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database i have a 3 columns one for the day, the second for the month and third for year it look something like this:

```
 Day |   Month | Year 
 2         1      2018
 17        9      2017
```

I want to group the days to weeks in sql, all the examples i saw where in the format "2018-5-2" in one column. How can i do it in sql?

Comment: What you want to achieve is unclear.

Comment: i want to to group days to weeks (7 days) for example from 2-1-2018 till 8-1-2018

Comment: So weeks start on Tuesday? That's an important detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to extract the year and the week:

```
select yearweek(date(concat_ws('-', year, month, day)))
```

This can be incorporated into an aggregation query, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT
  WEEK(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(Day, '/', Month, '/', Year), '%dd/%mm/%YYYY')) AS Weeknumber
FROM YOURTABLE
GROUP BY WEEK(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(Day, '/', Month, '/', Year), '%dd/%mm/%YYYY'))
```

It combines your datevalues into a DATE and then it uses the WEEK function to extract the weeknumber from that date. If you also want to select the date itself (`STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(Day, '/', Month, '/', Year), '%dd/%mm/%YYYY')`) then grouping on the weeknumber wont make much sense, but you didnt mention that in your post.